# Change the deskbar applet icon

Tags: icons

Can anybody explain me how I can change the deskbar panel-applet icon? I' ve try a few methods but no one works... I' ve try to change the .png file in the 'usr/share/deskbar-applet/art' folder and also I' ve try to add an icon called dekbar-applet.png in the current icon theme folder in 'usr/share/icons'. Thanks in advance.

Sorry for my bad english but I' m italian.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=498890). Summary (all text by [ayisu](http://ubuntuforums.org/member.php?u=21941)):

For example, if you're using the Human icon theme, create this directory structure (the new custom logo is in bold).

```
/home/username/.icons/Human/scalable/places/distributor-logo.png
```

Then press Alt-F2 and type:

```
killall gnome-panel
```